# What is the difference between core.entity_form_mode and core.entity_form_display?

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm trying to learn how to configure content types and form modes programmatically in Drupal 8. I've created the following using the UI:

- A content type named `book`
- A form mode for content, named `foo`
- A view mode for content, named `bar`

When I run `drush cget`, I get this list:

```
...
[36] core.entity_form_display.node.book.default
[37] core.entity_form_mode.node.foo
[38] core.entity_form_mode.user.register
[39] core.entity_view_display.node.book.default
[40] core.entity_view_display.node.book.teaser
[41] core.entity_view_mode.node.bar
[42] core.entity_view_mode.node.full
[43] core.entity_view_mode.node.rss
[44] core.entity_view_mode.node.search_index
[45] core.entity_view_mode.node.search_result
[46] core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser
[47] core.entity_view_mode.user.compact
[48] core.entity_view_mode.user.full
...
```

What is the difference between the `entity_form_display` configuration (36) and the `entity_form_mode` configurations (37, 38)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`entity_form_mode` would be the *form mode* (/admin/structure/display-modes/form)

- 37 - Form mode `foo` available for use on `node` entities (shows as
  content on the link above)
- 38 - Form mode `register` available on
  `user` entities.

`entity_form_display` is the configuration for that mode on a specific bundle - how the fields are arranged (/admin/structure/types/manage/book/form-display/{form_mode}) - in your case `form_mode` would be foo.

- 36 - Form display settings for the `default` display on the `book` bundle (content type) of the `node` entity.

The reason `36` is `default` is because you have arranged your form display (/admin/structure/types/manage/book/form-display) but you haven't enabled your `foo` mode.

At the bottom of that page is a fieldset called "Custom display settings". Expand that and you can enable your `foo` display for that content type.

[image]

In the picture, I have a created a `form mode` called `Inline Entity Form`, yours should say `foo`

Comment: Amazing! Now that I've enabled the custom display settings, I also have `core.entity_form_display.node.book.foo`, which I then exported with `drush cget` to get example code for my custom module.

Comment: also you can give thees from modes routs with https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_routing